# How to implement Zebra Striping in handlebar.js tables?

Tags: handlebars.js

I found out that we can leverage an @index in an #each helper, but that doesn't seem to help much.

I am trying to implement optional zebra striping in some handlebar templates.

```
{#if ((@index % 2) == 0) }}
    <tr class="darkRow">
{{else}}
    <tr>
{{/if}}
```

But when I compile the template the error is

```
>> Error: Parse error on line 3:
        {{#if ((@index % 2) == 0)
>> ----------------------^
>> Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Why don’t you just use CSS for this …? `:nth-child(even/odd)`

Comment: Browser compatibility.  Must be supported as far back as IE8. http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Do your logic before passing the data context to handlebar, then just check if the variable is true or false in the handlebar if statement.

Comment: That amounts to so much overhead over the long run.  There has to be a way to do it as the table is generated just with a simple modulo check, isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented my own solution by modifying the each helper.  Here's my new each code in the handlebars.js file

```
instance.registerHelper('each', function(context, options) {
  var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
  var i = 0, ret = "", data;

  if (isFunction(context)) { context = context.call(this); }

  if (options.data) {
    data = createFrame(options.data);
  }

  if(context && typeof context === 'object') {
    if (isArray(context)) {
      for(var j = context.length; i<j; i++) {
        if (data) {
          // For zebra tables
          data.zebra = (((i+1)%2) == 0) ? "even" : "odd";
          // end mod
          data.index = i;
          data.first = (i === 0);
          data.last  = (i === (context.length-1));
        }
        ret = ret + fn(context[i], { data: data });
      }
    } else {
      for(var key in context) {
        if(context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if(data) { 
            data.key = key; 
            data.index = i;
            data.first = (i === 0);
          }
          ret = ret + fn(context[key], {data: data});
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if(i === 0){
    ret = inverse(this);
  }

  return ret;
});
```

And I use it in {{#each xx}} loops in my templates by putting the class="{{@zebra}}" on my divs or trs.

Hope this helps others!